# Multiple separate Swagger documentations: internal and external

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, nswag

Is it possible to expose two Swagger UIs, let's say `public` and `internal` with NSwag?

I've tried with `.AddSwaggerDocument(ConfigurePublic);` + `.AddSwaggerDocument(ConfigureInternal);` but this generates two versions that are selectable from a single UI doc.

The API over time will have multiple versions (e.g. *v1*, *v2*) each with public and internal 'pools' of methods.

In the example of two *functional* versions (*v1*, *v2*) I thought of having four api versions *v1*, *v2*, *v1-internal*, and *v2-internal*, but I don't know how to create two UI paths, `/docs` showing *v1* and *v2* and `/docs-internal` showing *v1-internal*, and *v2-internal*. (Ideally I'd like to have only two versions and just mark methods as public/internal)

That the internal document is technically accessible to the public if they know the url is not a problem, it just cannot be visible in the pubic version of the Swagger UI.

Comment: What is the difference between public and internal? Is it a different deployment, a different user sending the request or what?

Comment: Internal endpoints are meant only for users within the organisation. Things public users should, could, and need not to call. 
For example: Only admin users are allowed to create a device and all users are allowed to update it.

Comment: @grek40 Imagine that you run a zoo and you need to produce two maps: a map for visitors which shows public paths and where animals are (visitor map); and a map for staff which shows private gates (which a locked), access doors (which are locked), internal phones (anybody can use them, but you don't want visitors to know where they are) (internal map).

Comment: imagine you are a random person. WHERE do you go, WHAT do you do and/or need to possess in order to convince WHOM to get one of those neat maps for internal staff? Zoo:off - please try to explain those things in technical terms of your actual programming problem, instead of some zoo comparison.

Comment: @grek40 what have you not understood here? He wants to know a way to separate internal APIs and external APIs and show these API groups(internal & external) on different swagger URLs.